# System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage always give me English

Tags: c#, logging, key

i'm writing a Key Logger application, and i want it to detect the current input language,

i've 2 installed English - US, and Arabic (101)

this line should give me the current input language, but it always gives me English

`System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName`??

is there is another solution ?

Comment: Arabic (101) looks like a keyboard layout, not a language

Comment: Yes, i mean layout, (the input keyboard layout)

Answer (score 1):

`InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage` returns the current language for the *current thread*, in this case for your keylogger application.

You can P/Invoke `GetKeyboardLayout` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646296) if you want to retrieve the layout for other threads.